# Feature selection in parameter optimization

Tags: optimization, feature-selection

Let't say that $\theta$ is a vector or real numbers of the form $(\theta_1, \theta_2,\theta_3, ...,\theta_n)$ and $Obj(\theta)$ is a continuous function (objective function).  Let's further say that I want to minimize $Obj(\theta)$, but the search space is too big for a classical optimization algorithm.

Is there any method that would allow to heuristically rank $\theta_1, \theta_2,\theta_3, ...,\theta_n$, such that, even if $\theta_i$ with a low rank is omitted, the optimization algorithm would still give a relatively good result?

Comment: What do you mean by "the search space is too big for a classical optimization algorithm"?  If the $\theta_i$ are real numbers, and $Obj(\theta)$ is convex, plenty of optimization algorithms, e.g., Newton, will work just fine.

Comment: @jbowman it is not a given that $Obj(\theta)$ is a convex function

Comment: But even then, that's not an issue with the size of the search space, if you see what I mean.

Comment: @jbowman The search space is exponential to the number of parameters. It might become a problem if the evaluation of $Obj(\theta)$ is expensive.

Comment: I think you'll need to tell us more about your objective function; as written, this is basically "I have a function on the reals, how do I optimize it?" - a subject about which an entire book cannot do justice, much less an answer here :)